# Why do xterm's docs call ' ' a control character?

Tags: shell, language-agnostic, console, ansi-escape

I'm writing a parser for ANSI escape codes using xterm's docs as a guideline. Under the list of single character functions, they include:

```
SP Space.
```

Now, for most of the single character functions, I understand the purpose: `BEL`, for example, is going to require some special help from your terminal emulator to process, and `TAB` is likely to be involved in autocompletion rather than being printed as a normal character.

I can't imagine any situation where `SP` would need to be treated as anything other than a literal space character, so I'm considering dropping the `SP` control code from my parser. Would I risk anything by doing so? Is there a use for `SP` in the console that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Tab as an auto-completion feature is an input to the *shell*, and unrelated to parsing control sequences (which are inputs to the *terminal*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space isn't a "control" character.  In ASCII, the control characters are codes 0 to 31 (space is 32), and 127 (DEL).  The POSIX locale uses the same data, not coincidentally.

They are called *control* characters, because they allow the host (computer) to *control* (tell) the terminal to perform functions rather than simply print text:

- A space is actually "printing" in this regard because (like all of the other ASCII characters), it advances the carriage position by one column.  In the C language of course, a space is treated as non-graphic, which is a different shade of meaning.  *"Graphic"* characters are visible.
- In contrast, a `TAB` requires the terminal to do something special: move the carriage position by an amount that depends on where it happens to be at the moment.

"Carriage position" of course refers to printing terminals (such as those on which Unix was originally developed), or typewriters. The "carriage" (noun) is the mechanism which moved left/right to allow the terminal (or typewriter) to print at different positions along the line. "Carriage controls" in turn refer to the control characters which move the carriage left and right (other than as a side-effect of printing individual characters).  It's obvious if you have ever used a typewriter...

[image]

In [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), `SP` is shown for clarity (to be able to reuse that *name* in other places, e.g., where a 32 is actually part of a *control sequence*).  That wording was added in [patch #25](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_25) to support the description of the group of controls S7C1T, S8C1T, and DECSCL — setting ANSI conformance level, none of which fall within ECMA-48.

A quick check shows 8 *control sequences* containing a *space* (which happens to be a valid *intermediate byte*, per ECMA-48, just like semicolon, which is visually distinct and does not require a name in the control sequences descriptions — you might find [the PDF](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.pdf) clearer than the HTML).  None of those sequences are used in the obscure sense referred to in ECMA-48:

- ECMA 48 section 6.1.1 is talking about overstriking one character on another to render a mixture of the two.  This is very rare in video terminals, but assumed in most printing devices.  The closest to this in a terminfo description might be `ul` (underline character overstrikes), and reviewing the few possibilities, some of *those* appear to be incorrect.  xterm doesn't do that.
- ECMA 48 section 8.3.140 in its comment about "character escapement" is referring to proportional fonts or variable-width character pitch (again, very rare in video terminals, but implemented in some printing devices).  There are a few terminfo capabilities referring to *pitch*, and *all* of those are marked as "printer support".  ncurses has one entry ([att5310](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-att5310)) using the `cpi` capability.

So: if you are referring to xterm's documentation, it is unlikely that you intend your parser for any other use than for video terminals.  But if you intend it to be more general, then reading about printers would be a good way to improve your application.

Comment: How did you determine that ECMA 48 6.1.1 talks about overstriking characters?

Comment: It's the most like interpretation that I saw.  If you had a better one, you might have offered it in your answer.

Comment: There are other aspects (which I noticed on reading the whole section), but starting from a quote out of context doesn't lead to productive discussion.

Comment: I'm not sure we're reading the same section. The one I linked to describes what a terminal's display is, namely a series of lines consisting of a series of character positions, then goes on to describe the states a character position may be in, and (as quoted) states that the space state and the erased state may or may not be one and the same.

Comment: Sure: this is a special case in building up what is known about a given cell on the screen (which by the way is unrelated to OP's question about control characters).  In subsequent updates to the cell, the device (which could be a FAX machine) is allowed leeway under the standard to treat composition onto uninitialized cells differently from those which were explicitly initialized with a space.  (Offhand, I don't recall any real devices which do this -- if you have one in mind, this is your chance to continue the discussion).

Answer (score 1):

[ECMA 48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf) sheds some light on this.

tl;dr:

- Some terminals may choose to differentiate between erased characters and space characters.
- In terminals with variable width fonts, `SP` can be considered a control character that introduces a configurable amount of horizontal spacing.

Neither is really relevant today, so you're entirely free to just treat as just another character.

ECMA 48 section 6.1.1:

> Depending on the implementation, there may or may not be a distinction between a character position in
>   the erased state and a character position imaging SPACE

ECMA 48 section 8.3.140:

> SSW is used to establish for subsequent text the character escapement associated with the character
>   SPACE. The established escapement remains in effect until the next occurrence of SSW in the data
>   stream or until it is reset to the default value by a subsequent occurrence of CARRIAGE RETURN/LINE
>   FEED (CR/LF), CARRIAGE RETURN/FORM FEED (CR/FF), or of NEXT LINE (NEL) in the data
>   stream, see annex C.

Comment: Huh, I never knew. There's so much cruft in terminal emulator codes, it's hard to tell when it's the right decision to drop it. Thanks.